# Android Instant Apps multiple activities

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-instant-apps

just like all of you, I've made MyFirst Instant App from [AndroidInstantAppDemo](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/first-instant-app.html), but what if I want to add more activities into my app?

I want to provide multiple links for them.
Should I simply add all of those **activities** under `app` *module* and provide `dependencies{...  implementation project (":base") }` in `build.gradle`.
Along with that, adding the different `path` with same `host` address in `.manifest` file.

***Or***

Put all the activities under `base` *module* only.

If yes (2nd options), does that mean that we should transfer data from `app` module to `base` module, in order to add `InstantApp`  functionality into our project.

I think I'm not very familiar with all three modules of them, and the [PROJECT STRUCTURE](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/structure.html) just provided an overview of these modules. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Basically both your Instant app module and application module depends on feature modules. As far as I know Instant app and application module does not contain any activities.

Out of all these feature modules there should be a baseFeature module. The feature modules should be less than 4mb in size. Now, when a linked is clicked for an Instant app, Google Play downloads base + feature1 apks and installs them in background. If you wants to travel between feature modules you can do that by using deep links.

A feature module can contain any number of activities but with the constraint that it's size should be less than 4 mb.

> I will suggest not to put any activities in application module. Just make some feature modules and link them with a URL. The feature module works like a library generating an aar file for your installable app.

If you want to provide multiple links, maybe this can help - [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html)

Comment: I have a doubt, I'm working on a multi-feature non-AIA (Android Instant App) application and I want one of the feature to be an instant one. So do I simply perform the following steps?

**1**. Convert my `app` module into `base`/feature` module.
**2**. Create a new `app` module.
**3**. Create an`instantApp` module
**4**. Link all of them view `build.gradle`
Is that it?

Comment: Well, these are the ideal steps given in the Instant app documentation.

Comment: Check out this codelab that demonstrates how to convert your non-AIA project into one that includes the instant app: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/index.html#0
There are also some helpful sample apps for reference:  https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/samples.html